# MongoDB storageEngine from MMAPv1 to wiredTiger fassert() failure

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I am upgrading my cluster to wiredTiger using this site: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-replica-set-wiredtiger/

I have been having the following issue:

Environment details:

MongoDB 3.0.9 in a sharded cluster on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago). I have 4 shards, each one is a replica set with 3 members. I just recently upgraded all binaries from 2.4 to 3.0.9. Every server has updated binaries, I tried converting each replica set to wired tiger storage engine, but I was getting the following error when upgrading the secondary on one member server (shard 1):

```
2016-02-09T12:36:39.366-0500 F REPL     [rsSync] replication oplog stream went back in time. previous timestamp: 56b9c217:ab newest timestamp: 56b9b429:60. Op being applied: { ts: Timestamp 1455010857000|96, h: 2267356763748731326, v: 2, op: "d", ns: "General.Tickets", fromMigrate: true, b: true, o: { _id: ObjectId('566aec7bdfd4b700e73d64db') }
2016-02-09T12:36:39.366-0500 I -        [rsSync] Fatal Assertion 18905
2016-02-09T12:36:39.366-0500 I -        [rsSync]
***aborting after fassert() failure
```

This is an open bug with replication: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17081

Every other part of the cluster, the upgrade went flawlessly, however, now I am stuck with only the primary and one secondary on shard 1. I've attempted resyncing the broken member using MMAPv1 and Wired Tiger, but I continually get the error above. Because of this, one shard is stuck using MMAPV1, and that shard happens to have most of the data (700 GB).

I have also tried rebooting, re-installing the binaries, to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, the system time is diverging. Please check that using the `date` utility. Install `ntpd`, if necessary. Also make sure that your servers use the same TZ.

Comment: Hi Markus, I checked all servers in the cluster, they are all using ntpd and all have the same time and TZ.

Comment: And the same time? Even with ntpd, you can have a drift, for example when it is not working properly.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a script to SSH into each of the 12 servers and the time was the same.

Comment: Well, nothing I can help you with remotely, then.

Comment: We tried using the default of wiredTiger on an upgrade from 3.0.9 to 3.2.8 and had noticeable performance issues with the initial start.  Not sure what it was doing but it shut the DB down, no access for some time while I imagine it was converting the DB.  We eventually had to stick to mmapv1 and force that opt in our config file.  Anyone seen similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by dropping our giant collection. The rssync must have been hitting some limit since the giant collection had 4.5 billion documents.